# How to format new date object to MySQL format YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss in core JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

How to format JavaScript date object to MySQL format `YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss`?
I am trying send date to API what ever solution I get is to get data from API and format but I did not get any thing which format date to MySQL format.

PS

I know I can use moment.js but I want to do in core JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I found below solution

```js
var mydate = new Date().toISOString().replace("T"," ").split(".")[0];
console.log(mydate)
```

Comment: If you dont care about timezones, use the plan js solution. If you do, use moment.js.

Comment: converts to UTC not localtime